# VMware Fusion configuration files missing

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion

I need to set up port forwarding to my VM in Fusion 5. Everywhere on the net, the solution is described as editing the file:

```
/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf
```

However, on my install, that file doesn't exist. Neither does the vmnet8 directory.

Here is the full content of VMware stuff I have in /Library/Application Support/:

```
/Library/Application Support/
     VMware/
          VMware Fusion
               AdminWritable
               Shared
                    vmInventory
          usbarb.rules
     VMware Fusion
```

That's right: `/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/` exists but is empty. And there is no VMware folder in other Library directories on my system. I am running OS X 10.8.2.

I just reinstalled Fusion 5.02, no change. Meanwhile, I have 3 VMs that work just fine.

So how am I supposed to set up port forwarding with Fusion 5?

Thanks,

JD

Edit: in a hunch, I tried `ps ax | grep natd` which returned:

```
 9646   ??  S      0:00.01 /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-natd -s 7 -m /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.mac -c /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf
```

So it seems that the configurations files are now in the directory `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion`. I'll work from here and edit this question as I make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guides are all correct still but as of VMWare Fusion 5 the path is now at: `/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion`. You will find the "vmnet8" folder in there.